# Crypt/Decrypt + SHA in UTF8 Postgres

Tags: postgresql, sha, crypt

I've a trouble with data crypted in postgres. I've a column with UTF data crypted :

```
convert_from(decrypt(name::bytea, 'salt', 'bf'), 'UTF-8') => "mamanÃ©"
```

So, this is true, with "é" in UTF8. Now, if I hash this value :

```
encode(public.digest('mamanÃ©', 'sha1'), 'hex') => "2bfb316cf461d1a884e0b24c4d90de0bfe25f04f"
```

So, I have to obtain the same hash with this :

```
encode(public.digest(convert_from(decrypt(name::bytea, 'salt', 'bf'), 'UTF-8'), 'sha1'), 'hex') => "e16053f9fba5b1ef75b76eab82370c3264ee6263"
```

Why is it different?
I don't understand...

Thank you very much for all answers.
G.

Comment: Please clarify `decrypt` and `decrypt`.

Comment: Standard encrypt / decrypt : 
encrypt(data bytea, key bytea, type text) returns bytea and 
decrypt(data bytea, key bytea, type text) returns bytea
[link](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgcrypto.html)

Comment: Can we get a pg_dump of the table and the output of \encoding? I always get "decrypt error: Data not a multiple of block size" for the first query. I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4.5 with pgCrypto 1.1